# Could not resolve host: payments.paystation.co.nz

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-20.04

We have started to have an increasing "could not resolve host" errors from payments.paystation.co.nz.

When we asked them about it they stated the following: "Those errors aren't from a Paystation server, they're because your DNS resolver didn't get a response from the AWS Route 53 DNS servers that host payments.paystation.co.nz.  This could be because AWS had an issue, more likely a momentary loss of connectivity between your resolver and Route 53, or between your server and your resolver. DNS lookups are UDP and routinely fail - your client code should automatically retry to one of the other three Route 53 name servers, it shouldn't be costing you any business".

3 questions:

1. Does this sound accurate?
2. If they keep rotating the IP address of their server(s) wouldn't this cause the same issue?
3. How do you change your client code to make sure DNS is resolved after a failed attempt? I assume the server (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS) attempts automatically by default?

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: `1` yes - `2` no, not likely. The error has nothing to with the address(es) their servers use, but with your DNS client making and not receiving the required responses to DNS queries. - `3` that depends on the underlying error condition / code the DNS query for payments.paystation.co.nz

Comment: Route53 is possibly pointing at an AWS load balancer. The IPs of the load balancer can change at any time and shouldn't be cached, if they're cached it should be for seconds or a small number of minutes at most. I don't know the answer to the question but this might be interesting / useful information.

Comment: "DNS lookups are UDP" Wrong. DNS uses TCP AND UDP.